Populate multiple forms from single sheet
Not a coder. I've copy/pasted code from other sources to get a basic foundation, but I need help adding functionality.
I have a single Google Sheet with data in the "events" tab that I would like to use to automatically populate a dropdown menu in multiple different Google Forms.
The code I'm using is only setup for a single Form, and I need guidance in setting up the code so I can add more forms in the future to automatically populate.
The first form ID is 1jDopSo1ofeZpy_5rhL--bg3DpInidz2TtBmWfgKLfiw
The second form ID (which needs to be added to the code) is 1DhnRIqvFt0z4LXjKB0JI3Yl7zeUaHyQchBKTjDvMvj0
function updateDropdown() {
  // Get the form and the spreadsheet
  var form = FormApp.openById('1jDopSo1ofeZpy_5rhL--bg3DpInidz2TtBmWfgKLfiw');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('events');  

  // Get the data from the spreadsheet
  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var items = data.flat().filter(String);  

  // Put the dropdown question in the form
  var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
  var listItem = formItems[0].asListItem();  

  // Update the dropdown options
  listItem.setChoiceValues(items);

}

I found similar questions

Google App Script - pass multiple sheet ID through function
Using Apps Script to create multiple Forms from a Spreadsheet

but I'm not experienced enough to transpose either solution to my particular situation.

You will need to place the URL of each form into a list on sheet.  Next get this list an an array and loop through opening each form using FormApp.openByURL(URL), updating the dropdown on each form.
function updateDropdown() {
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('events');  

  // Get the data from the spreadsheet
  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var items = data.flat().filter(String);  
  
  //Get the list of form URLs from the spreadsheet in Column D for example
  var formLinks = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getDisplayValues()
  var formURLs = formlinks.flat().filter(string);
  
  for (var x = 0; x < formURLs.length; x++){
    //Open the form 
    var formToUpdate = FormApp.openByUrl(formURLs[x]);
    
    // Put the dropdown question in the form
    var formItems = formToUpdate.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
    var listItem = formItems[0].asListItem(); 
     
    // Update the dropdown options
    listItem.setChoiceValues(items);
    
  }


}


Thanks. I've updated the code, but now I'm getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asListItem'). I have tried setting a trigger for the script to run on change, and I'm still getting an error when making a change to the spreadsheet.

For the second form your updating, is the first question on the form a list type question? The variable formItems[0] indicates the very question on the form, which brings up the question are the forms identical in some way?

That's it! I just needed to add a blank dropdown question on the second form, then the script works to auto populate the options. Thank you
